# Should the word 'from' be between 'you' and 'receiving'?

Tags: prepositions

I recently visited a website and on its main page it had the following sentence:

> This makes it nearly impossible for anyone to stop you receiving payments or using services

This feels unnatural to me, and I don't know the reason why. I think it should be written as:

> This makes it nearly impossible for anyone to stop you **from** receiving payments or using services.

I googled and all I came up with was this site which does list some 'from receiving' usages:
https://sentence.yourdictionary.com/receiving

To use ‘from’ or not to use ‘from’? That is my question.
Is this British English by chance?

Answer (score 1):

**Most native speakers would understand, but the omission of *from* is not helpful.**

Here is an Ngram, confirming your feeling that something was 'missing':

[image]

I cannot find any reference to this style of writing being a British trend, but it is clearly more common to keep 'from' in these cases than to omit it.

[Here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22stop+you+using%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:2000,cd_max:2099&tbm=bks&source=lnt&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjah-DjycDrAhWEhOAKHfVYDggQpwUIIQ&biw=1277&bih=645&dpr=2) are some more examples of this phenomenon from the 21st century.